# Stop Runnable while Destroying Activity

Tags: android

I have the following runnable thread in my code.

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
               int totalDuration = PlayIt.getDuration();
               int currentDuration = PlayIt.currentLocation();

               // Displaying Total Duration time
               songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
               // Displaying time completed playing
               songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

               // Updating progress bar
               int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
               //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
               songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

               // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
               mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
           }
        };
```

I want to stop this runnable while destroying activity. I used this code.

```
@Override
     public void onDestroy(){
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(mUpdateTimeTask);
        PlayIt.release();
        super.onDestroy();
     }
```

But it is not working.

I also tried,

```
mHandler.removeCallback(mUpdateTimeTask)
```

But it is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to prevent your postDelay-ed Runnable from executing after Activity has terminated is using Activity.isFinishing(), in which case you don't need to do anything in onDestroy.

```
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
          if (isFinishing()) return;
          .....
```

Another way is via a flag (not a fancy code, just to give an idea):

```
protected boolean stopFlag = false;

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
              if (stopFlag) return;

       ..........
       }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopFlag = true;
    .....
    super.onDestroy();   
}
```